# VS 2017 debugging, wrong exceptions

Tags: wpf, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I have a simple .Net 4.5 WPF application and debug it in VS2015 and VS2017. VS2017 gives me unclear exceptions:

```
Mat src = new Mat("lenna.png", ImreadModes.GrayScale); // image does not exist
```

VS2015 exception raises on the right line and is clear:

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in OpenCvSharp.dll but was not handled in user code
```

VS2017 does not go to the right cs line number and raises:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
```

I think there is something wrong with my VS2017 configuration?

Comment: Does the XamlParseException have an inner exception?

Comment: {"":"lenna.png"}

Comment: You should be able to find the necessary information in the inner exception.

Comment: It doesn't give me the line number or exception detail (file not found). VS also doesn't jump to the code line.

Comment: `XamlParseException` cannot be thrown on the line you have shown. This exception tells that there is an error in XAML, not in code (technically in code but in autogenerated code). Are you sure that solutions are identical in VS2015 and VS2017? Or this line executed from XAML? Look at the Details section of the exception.

Comment: That is your file not found exception wrapped in XAML, what I mean is if there is an element in the xaml that fails to create on start, i.e. Constructor, then you will get that sort of exception, it seems that VS2017 doesn't seem to handle it as good as the VS2015.

Comment: so this is a VS2017 issue and not a configuration problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a Visual Studio settings issue. Bring up the Exception Settings window by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> (or go to Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings) and make sure that the `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` is checked under Break When Thrown -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions.

**Manage exceptions with the debugger in Visual Studio:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger